# How to read yaml file from master using Jenkinsfile pipeline script when jenkins job is running on slave machine?

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, master-slave

I am building a Shared Library(I'm not a CI engineer) for Jenkins pipeline. As a part of it, we are thinking of giving configurations in yaml file and have Jenkinsfile pipeline script read from the yaml file.

So, we are planning to commit Jenkinsfile and yaml file in one git repository (let's say repo A) and the job is going to run on a slave machine utilising another git repository (let's say repo B). The Jenkinsfile will be executed from master after it clones repo A. The yaml file is also in master workspace. In the slave, repo B will be cloned and a build will take place as defined in the Jenkinsfile. But the question I have is, how do I read yaml file from Jenkinsfile script without having to clone repo A in slave i.e., how I reference a file present in master and not in slave from Jenkinsfile? This question arises because, whatever file I am trying to open is being opened from slave and not from master.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Soemthing I forgot to mention. We actually thought of using stash from master and unstash in slave. But the problem is that we do only the job configurations and the environment is provided to us by some other team which also provides to many other teams. Because of that, master rarely has executors free. So, even when we run the job, it hangs waiting for the master to be free. Is there any other way to load the yaml file when the pipeline script is being loaded in master's memory?

Comment: Are the jobs on master and slaves related (i. e. are jobs on slave launched by jobs on master) or are they triggered independently?

Comment: There are no jobs configured by us to run on master. What I meant is when pipeline script is configured in job configuration to take from scm, it gets cloned in master workspace, pipeline scipt is loaded and I need to read the yaml file from master

Comment: Why not just retrieve the yaml file from repo A in slave? If a full clone is too much overhead, you could also call ["git archive"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) to only get the yaml file from the remote repo. In my experience it is pretty efficient as it doesn't create a local repo.

Comment: Yes, cloning on the slave machine is my last resort. I just wanted to check if there are other means. But the "git_archive" is something I did not not know about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another idea: use Groovy `File` class to read yaml file (as Groovy/Java classes always run on master, even if job runs on slave), then use Jenkins `writeFile` step to write it to slave workspace. E. g. `def yaml = new File(fullPathOnMaster).text; writeFile path: relativePathOnSlave, text: yaml`

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way is to use the [`stash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build). Stashes are temporary packages that can be created on one node and copied to any other node.

There is some overhead on master for the package creation so stashes are not recommended for really big files, but they are ideally suited for your usecase of transfering a small configuration file.

```groovy
node('master') {
    // Create temporary stash package on master
    stash name: 'MyConfiguration', includes: 'SomeFile.yaml'
}

node('MySlave') {
    // Copy to and extract the stash package on slave
    unstash 'MyConfiguration'
}
```

This expects 'SomeFile.yaml' to be in the workspace on master and will also extract it to workspace on slave. In case you want a sub directory of `WORKSPACE`, simply wrap the `stash` and/or `unstash` steps in a `dir` step.

Comment: We actually thought of this. But the problem is that we do only the job configurations and the environment is provided to us by some other team which also provides to many other teams. Because of that, master rarely has executors free. So, even when we run the job, it hangs waiting for the master to be free. Sorry, should have mentioned in the question. I'll edit it now.